# COUNTIFS formula

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to keep track of student movement throughout the day.  I have created a spread sheet for each classroom that students will sign out on, I have then used the `=importrange()` function to grab all data from each classroom, now I am trying to use `=countifs()` to search through all of these sheets and match student names and dates and give me a total.  On my master sheet I want to type a Student Name in A2 and then a date in B2, then use the `countifs` function to run through the sheets and give me a total.  Each time it keeps returning "0".

I have the following:  `=countifs(Krohn!A:A,A2,Krohn!C:C,"*"&B2&"*")`

Here is a link to the sheets.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hnm5wtLvC4AboohTdH7hFBiHCXAlHhGXISD0a9W9QV4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the formula is on the sheet "Master Count"

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating just one [form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888) instead of sharing many spreadsheets? The form could include a drop-down menu to choose the classroom and additional drop-down menus and text boxes to enter the rest of the data.

Form responses automatically appear in a separate tab in the spreadsheet in a row-oriented fashion and are thus easy to process with spreadsheet functions such as `query()` and `filter()`.